# how to query for the 2 id's field whose value present in the same table B

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
**Friends Table**     
-------------------------
id    seller_id    buyer_id
-------------------------
1     101           102
2     102           104
3     103           101
4     104           101

**Name Table**     
--------------
id    name_id
--------------
101   Robin
102   Goblin
103   Ork
104   Wizard
```

I just want the Friends table to display the Name instead of name_id and friend_id.
I know its easy but I cant find proper word to goggle for it. please help..

Comment: use join in sqlite query.

Comment: yes I know I have to use join query but how. please post the query string it won't be long...

Comment: I post an answer. Give a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two times `JOIN` to achieve that :

```
SELECT 
    f.id
    , n1.name_id As seller
    , n2.name_id As buyer
FROM Friends f
    INNER JOIN Name n1 ON n1.id = f.seller_id
    INNER JOIN Name n2 ON n2.id = f.buyer_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select f.id,n.name_id as "seller_id",nb.name_id  as "buyer_id"
from [Friends Table] f
join [Name Table] n on n.seller_id=f.id
join [Name Table] nb on nb.buyer_id=f.id
```

Comment: @donison24x7: Try this

Answer (score 1):

this may help you.

```
SELECT F.friend_id, F.id N.name_id FROM Friends_Table F INNER JOIN Name_Table N ON F.id= N.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
select n.name_id
from Friends as f
join Name as n
on f.id = n.id
group by n.name_id
```